# Calculate Bounding Rect Given Two Aspect Ratios

Tags: math, uiview, frame, uicollectionviewlayout

I have two rectangles, each with fixed aspect ratios. Given a width of x how do I calculate the height of a rectangle that would enclose the two rectangles without leaving any gaps?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve the following equations for `h`:

```
r1 = w1 / h
r2 = w2 / h
w = w1 + w2
```

The solution is:

```
h = w / (r1 + r2)
```